# For loop not producing any outcome

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, countif

My for loop is not giving an error message when it runs, however it is also not doing anything! Basically I want it to look through column 3 on 2nd tab to find if that work order number is on the table in tab one (column 2) if not add the row to end of list in worksheet one

```
Sub If_a_range_contains_a_specific_value()
'declare a variable
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("In Progress Workorders")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = Worksheets("MASTER")

 
Dim i As Integer
'lastrow = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count
For i = 4 To i = 10
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ws2.Range("B3:B15"), ws.Cells(i, 3)) > 0 Then
   ws.Range("R8") = "In Range"
        Else
        ws2.Cells(lastrow + 1, 2) = ws.Cells(i, 3)
        lastrow = lastrow + 1
    End If
Next
Exit Sub
 
 
 
End Sub
```

Comment: `For i = 4 To 10`

Comment: If you have the `countif formula = 0` then you would not require an `else`

Answer (score 1):

looks like your For syntax is wrong, maybe you should start from here:

```
For i = 4 To 10
...
Next i
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement

Comment: This is what happens:
For i = 4 To I = 10
is interpreted by VBA as:
For I = 4 To CInt(I=10)
CInt(I=10) is equal to CInt(False) which is zero.
In a nutshell you wrote
For i = 4 To 0
so the cycle will never be executed.